# Vertical QToolBar from MainWindow

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtoolbar

What I want: http://puu.sh/3oUjh.jpg
What I have: http://puu.sh/3oUnI.png

The toolbar is made in mainwindow.ui, ive tried `ui->_toolbar->setLayoutDirection(Qt::LeftToolBarArea);`

But I get this error: `no matching function for call to 'QToolBar::setLayoutDirection(Qt::ToolBarArea)'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `QToolBar::orientation` property:

```
ui->myToolbar->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
```

You can also use `QMainWindow::addToolBar`:

```
addToolBar(Qt::LeftToolBarArea, ui->myToolbar);
```

Note that by default the user is able to drag toolbars and attach them to any side of the main window.

Comment: @Cpp and Qt Beginner:  Pssst, you should mark the replies as answers if it helped you

Comment: haven't had a chance to try it yet. was not my upvote =/. I'll be sure to mark as answered if it works.

Comment: addToolBar(Qt::LeftToolBarArea, ui->myToolbar);
worked wonders

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong enum for setLayoutDirection:

```
// Don't use this.  You need to use a different method 
// if you want it placed against the left side.
enum ToolBarArea {
    LeftToolBarArea = 0x1,
    RightToolBarArea = 0x2,
    TopToolBarArea = 0x4,
    BottomToolBarArea = 0x8,

    ToolBarArea_Mask = 0xf,
    AllToolBarAreas = ToolBarArea_Mask,
    NoToolBarArea = 0
};
```

You need to use something from Qt::LayoutDirection:

```
enum LayoutDirection {
    LeftToRight,
    RightToLeft,
    LayoutDirectionAuto
};

ui->_toolbar->setLayoutDirection(Qt::LeftToRight);
```